# PDF file conversion in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am using beanshell sampler to convert one pdf content to another pdf .

In beanshell sampler put this following code :

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

File file = new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Downloads\\Instructions.pdf");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
for (int i; (i = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) 
{
bos.write(buffer, 0, i);
}
in.close();
byte[] pdfdata= bos.toByteArray();
bos.close();
vars.put("pdfdata",new String(pdfdata));
```

then use `${pdfdata}` variable in beanshell post processor to write the content in another pdf

Beanshell PostProcessor code :-

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("newresult1.pdf",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(vars.get("pdfdata"));
out.close();
fstream.close();
```

File created but when open that file it's blank. No content is displayed in that file.
So can anyone please tell me how to fix this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.
2. I fail to see any "conversion" in your code, it looks like you're just trying to [make a copy of the file](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_file_io.htm), with Groovy it will be only one line:

   ```
   new File('newresult1.pdf').bytes = new File('C:\\Users\\hp\\Downloads\\Instructions.pdf').bytes
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)