# JMeter - PDF Conversions Produces Blank PDF's

Tags: jmeter, file-conversion

I know there are similar articles like [PDF file conversion in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73050364/pdf-file-conversion-in-jmeter) but they do not answer the actual problem which is "when converting a PDF to a variable/object/property then back to PDF the document whilst the correct number of pages is 'whit on white'= blank.

is there a way to :

1. Create a runtime variable/object/property from an existing PDF file that can be used in a subsequent action.
2. Here other actions happen in the Test Plan but they do not
3. Convert the variable/object/property back to a pdf so that when viewed it does not contain just blanks.

Notes: I do not just wish to just copy a to pdf to pdf.
I have also tried creating a UDV form the pdf using the following posted on here without success too.
${__groovy(vars.putObject("hoping_its_a_pdf"), new File("my_original.pdf"))}

Reading other posts here I have also noticed strange character strings like "%âãÏÓ" when using both putObect and props.put when viewing them post creation but as the article said, most probably page break characters or similar so I have ignored those for now as I assumed it is the conversion and not the reason for the blank content.

Can someone please assist as this is now 4 weeks in and I still have white pdf's.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot state what's wrong with the code which you're copying and pasting from some random sources.

There is not problem with storing the PDF file in [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and creating the file back from them.

Demo:

[image]

There are 2 problems the only piece of "code" you're sharing:

1. Your way of using [vars.putObject() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) is wrong, it takes 2 parameters: variable name and the object value. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands
2. Apart from this the function itself is syntactically incorrect, you need to [escape any comma in the function with a backslash](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions)

So if you change your:

```
${__groovy(vars.putObject("hoping_its_a_pdf"), new File("my_original.pdf"))}
```

to

```
${__groovy(vars.putObject('hoping_its_a_pdf'\, new File('my_original.pdf')),)}
```

at least this bit will start working as you expect.